# router.currentRoute is showing different route than router.currentRoute.value

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm trying to get the current route of a component but `router.currentRoute` is showing some weird behaviour.

`router.currentRoute` shows the expected route `/admin`:

```
RefImpl {__v_isShallow: true, dep: undefined, __v_isRef: true, _rawValue: {…}, _value: {…}}
dep: Set(1) {ReactiveEffect}
__v_isRef: true
__v_isShallow: true
_rawValue: {fullPath: '/admin', path: '/admin', query: {…}, hash: '', name: 'login', …}
_value: {fullPath: '/admin', path: '/admin', query: {…}, hash: '', name: 'login', …}
value: Object
    fullPath: "/admin"
    hash: ""
    href: "/admin"
    matched: [{…}]
    meta: {}
    name: "login"
    params: {}
    path: "/admin"
    query: {}
    redirectedFrom: undefined
    [[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

but `router.currentRoute.value` shows route `/`:

```
{path: '/', name: undefined, params: {…}, query: {…}, hash: '', …}
fullPath: "/"
hash: ""
matched: []
meta: {}
name: undefined
params: {}
path: "/"
query: {}
redirectedFrom: undefined
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

hence I can't use `router.currentRoute.value.path` which should show the current route. Is this behaviour expected? How do I get the current route of the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given by the formatting it seems you are using `console.log` (or similar) API to observe the code effects.

Note that what almost all modern browsers shows in the console is the "lazy" view of the object (when logging objects)

Check [this example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) (which roughly follows the data structures used by Vue Router)

1. Open example
2. Open Dev Tools - Console
3. Click the button twice or more
4. Only now explore the logged values

Result: Each log of `router.currentRoute` shows exactly same value (opposed to logs of `router.currentRoute.value`)

Now try the same thing but unfold the logged object after each click...

**TL:DR Do not trust the console!** - the value you see is not necessarily the value of the object at the time `console.log` was executed.

To workaround the issue use `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))` instead...

Comment: The stringified object shows the empty path. I'll look into it. Thank you.